# How do I get Map to open at a specific location?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to put a marker on a map and then show the marker. I am stumped. If I use this code, the marker is first showed and then replaced with a map centred in the US.

```
public void showOnMap(Coord location) {
    Form mapDemo = new Form("Maps", new LayeredLayout());
    if (BrowserComponent.isNativeBrowserSupported()) {
        System.out.println("Browser Component Supported");
        MapContainer mc = new MapContainer(MAPS_KEY);
        mapDemo.add(mc);
        Container markers = new Container();
        markers.setLayout(new MapLayout(mc, markers));
        mapDemo.add(markers);

        Coord moscone = new Coord(37.7831, -122.401558);
        //Coord moscone = new Coord(location);
        Button mosconeButton = new Button("");
        mosconeButton.setUIID("Label");
        FontImage.setMaterialIcon(mosconeButton, FontImage.MATERIAL_PLACE);
        markers.add(moscone, mosconeButton);

        mc.zoom(moscone, 5);
        mc.setCameraPosition(moscone);
        //mc.setShowMyLocation(true);
    } else {
        // iOS Screenshot process...
        mapDemo.add(new Label("Loading, please wait...."));
    }
    mapDemo.show();
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing this on the device or on the simulator?  Are you using the latest version of the maps cn1lib?

Comment: I see this happening in the simulator, it looks like a regression with the latest library. Please file an issue on this http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/new

Comment: On the simulator. Ok  I’ll file the issue.

Comment: I think this issue was resolved in the latest cn1lib update. Notice that there might be a different regression in that update too

Comment: Yes. Just checked. It is resolved. However it seems that when you put a component as a marker, when you move/pan the map, the market stays fixed in its position on the screen rather than moving with the map.

Comment: Steve was having an issue reproducing this on his end in the issue, I suggest following up there.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, and should work for you, I hope.

```
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: I am using codenamone. These APIs you mention don't exist.

Comment: My dearest apologies, but if you try something like this with codenameone, it should work.